# Android O VirtualBox can't set up device - Google Play services keep crashing

Tags: google-play-services, 8.0-oreo, 8.1-oreo, android-x86, virtualbox

I have an Android O Virtualbox and when I go to set it up, it asks if I want to set it up with data from my old phone or start new. I've tried both options, and it says that the Google Play Services have stopped, every time I try. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score -1):

Tested for ubuntu 16.04.

- You can use this link to follow steps.,

`https://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/`

- for 32-bit system use this link for latest Android-orio.,

`https://osdn.net/projects/android-x86/downloads/69704/android-x86-8.1-r2.iso/`

- for 64-bit system i used this link for latest Android-orio.,

`https://osdn.net/projects/android-x86/downloads/69704/android-x86_64-8.1-r2.iso/`

and at one step there is no Primary or Logical partition option as mention in the post, there you have to create a partition, you have to enter some values too, where there is default just let it be like it, and enter 8300 for linux. Actually that and name of the pariton is the only value i've entered in rest i just pressed enter.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see this answering the question. The question is about Google Play Services on Setup Wizard, not about installing Android in VirtualBox.

Comment: @AndrewT. you want me to delete the answer?